# Run PHP loop asynchronously

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have an app which needs to show an alert at a certain time and I need to run some PHP in the background.

```
echo "My content";

// Run below code asynchronously without interrupting the client's page from loading

sleep(60);
header("location: alert.php");
```

Instead of the client's browser waiting for all the PHP to finish, I want it to load and then to display the alert after 60 seconds. I also cannot use JavaScript for this for security reasons.

Comment: You need some clientside code to trigger the async request

Comment: Please explain the security issues you're concerned about. Perhaps on the PHP side you could return different data after whatever delay you need, but you'll still need to do *something* in Javascript to perform that late load.

Comment: The alert must show up. In reality, it's a redirect.

Comment: The content can only be displayed for a limited amount of time, and then it must redirect. I've though about using JS, but it could somehow be stopped, couldn't it? `setTimeout(myRedirectFunc, 60000)`

Comment: Are you sure the PHP always takes exactly 60 seconds? Why not show the alert after the PHP finishes, even if it takes a bit more or less than 60 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You're saying "alert" but do you mean a Javascript `alert()` or some other sort of alert like a block of HTML, or perhaps an HTML modal?

In any case, why not just have your PHP script do this:

```
ob_end_flush(); // Disable output buffering
echo "My content. Please wait...";
do_some_stuff_that_takes_a_while();
echo "<script>alert('Done!');</script>";
```

Comment: Firstly, it's a html file, see the question, and secondly, it blocks. Your code doesn't `echo` the content. It just keeps on loading until `do_some_stuff_that_takes_a_while()` finishes.

Comment: What is an HTML file? The alert? The original question doesn't mention "HTML". In any case, are you saying that "My content..." doesn't show until `do_some_stuff_that_takes_a_while()` finishes? That may be because your system caches/buffers in some other way. `ob_end_flush()` disables PHP's caching, but caching may still be happening at the server or proxy level. If nothing else, try adding a `\n` to the "please wait..." message to see if that flushes the buffer.

Comment: It redirects to a html file: `location: alert.php`